# Start service on boot and repeat

Tags: android, alarm

im trying to do somekind of auto GoogleDrive backup(uploading a file) timer, but i cant set the specific time, even if i set to 5 seconds(testing purpouse, it just run every 1minute) and when the user reboot the phone, it only RUN one time (the Alarm is not called =/, so the application has to be opened one time after the boot)

Manifest Configuration:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application...>

 <receiver
            android:name=".Tools.AutoBackupAlarmBroadCast"
            android:process=":remote" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".Tools.AutoBackupService"
            android:exported="false" />


</application>
```

and with this WakeBroadCast:

```
public class AutoBackupBootStarter extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AutoBackupService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

make sure that the  AutoBackupAlarm is called on boot, but it only happens ONE time, i need it to start the trigger to repeat by the user setted time(will get it from shared Preferences)

the service:

AutoBackupService:

```
public class AutoBackupService extends IntentService {
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     */
    public AutoBackupService() {
        super("AutoBackup");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
//HERE i must start the Async to make the GoogleDrive Backup
//the next doubt will be how can i get sharedpreferences and activity to pass to the async from HERE?

        Log.d("BACKUP", "AutoBackupLogTest");
    }
}
```

the broadcast

```
public class AutoBackupAlarmBroadCast extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 12345;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AutoBackupService.class);
        i.putExtra("foo", "bar");
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

the AlarmFunction called on onCreate, that almost works how i want, it cant repeat every 5 seconds like the time below, it only show every 1 minute

```
   public void scheduleAlarm() {
        // Construct an intent that will execute the AlarmReceiver
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AutoBackupAlarmBroadCast.class);
        // Create a PendingIntent to be triggered when the alarm goes off
        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, AutoBackupAlarmBroadCast.REQUEST_CODE,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        // Setup periodic alarm every 5 seconds
        long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); // alarm is set right away
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        // First parameter is the type: ELAPSED_REALTIME, ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP
        // Interval can be INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, INTERVAL_HOUR, INTERVAL_DAY
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis,
                1 * 5 * 1000, pIntent);
    }
```

Comment: AFAIK setInexactRepeating() doesn't guarantee to alarm/trigger at fixed time interval if you test app on Lollipop or above.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to repeat task after particular time interval

```
    boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 444, new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

    if(!alarmUp){

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent DataSyncIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 444, DataSyncIntent, 0);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(),
                15 * 60000, // 60000 = 1 minute,
                pendingIntent);

    }
```